Implementing Database backend to predictive model changing predictions
I created a predictive model that predicts if a customer is likely to default on a loan based on inputted variables, the variables are temp stored in an array for the prediction and I recently implemented a database for past predictions to be stored in. Since implementing the database, every prediction regardless of variables has the same output. Before adding the db everything worked fine and I am unsure on how the db has effected the predictions themselves.
I can only imagine the error would lie in one of these two blocks
model = joblib.load('credit_model.joblib')
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def form():
    form = CreditForm()
    prediction_result = None

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        data = [
            form.age.data,
            form.income.data,
            form.home.data,
            form.emp_length.data,
            form.intent.data,
            form.amount.data,
            form.rate.data,
            form.status.data,
            form.percent_income.data,
            form.cred_length.data
        ]

        column_names = ['Age', 'Income', 'Home', 'Emp_length', 'Intent', 'Amount', 'Rate', 'Status', 'Percent_income',
                        'Cred_length']

        data_df = pd.DataFrame([data], columns=column_names)

        prediction = model.predict(data_df)

        last_prediction = prediction[0]
        if prediction[0] == 1:
            prediction_result = "It is likely that the customer WILL NOT default on the loan."
        else:
            prediction_result = "It is likely that the customer WILL default on the loan."

        print(prediction_result)

        new_credit = credit(
            age=form.age.data,
            income=form.income.data,
            home=form.home.data,
            emp_length=form.emp_length.data,
            intent=form.intent.data,
            amount=form.amount.data,
            rate=form.rate.data,
            status=form.status.data,
            percent_income=form.percent_income.data,
            cred_length=form.cred_length.data,
            prediction_result=last_prediction
        )

        db.session.add(new_credit)

        db.session.commit()
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            flash('Please correct the errors in the form!', 'error')

    return render_template('main/index.html', form=form, prediction_result=prediction_result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

Or:
class credit(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'credit_features'

    # PK
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

    age = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    income = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    home = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    emp_length = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    intent = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    amount = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    rate = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    status = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    percent_income = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    cred_length = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    prediction_result = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, age, income, home, emp_length, intent, amount, rate, status, percent_income, cred_length,
                 prediction_result):
        self.age = age
        self.income = income
        self.home = home
        self.emp_length = emp_length
        self.intent = intent
        self.amount = amount
        self.rate = rate
        self.status = status
        self.percent_income = percent_income
        self.cred_length = cred_length
        self.prediction_result = prediction_result

Looked to see if there was anywhere where the db altered the input or array but I cannot seem to spot the issue.

In the code samples, the prediction is only ever saved to the database after being computed. Do the saved results differ from the results shown to the visitor to the webpage?

The saved results are the same as what is shown. I made it so the variables entered were entered into an array and the prediction was made based off of that then saved to the db, I thought that would be best performance wise.

It sounds like the problem is with the prediction, not the database.
